# MySQL query to find the department with the lowest average age of employees

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm given this schema:

```
Emp(eid: integer,ename: string,age: integer,salary: real)
Works(eid:integer,did: integer,pct_time: integer)
Dept(did:integer,budget: real,managerid:integer)
```

I've written this query which lists the department codes along with the average ages of employees just fine:

```
SELECT d.did AS Department, AVG(e.age) AS Average_Age
FROM Emp e, Works w, Dept d
WHERE e.eid=w.eid AND w.did=d.did
GROUP BY d.did
```

However, when I try to do something like this:

```
SELECT Department, MIN(Average_Age)
FROM 
(
SELECT d.did AS Department, AVG(e.age) AS Average_Age
WHERE e.eid=w.eid AND w.did=d.did
GROUP BY d.did
) MyTable
```

It returns the wrong Department ID. It just returns 0 for that column but it returns the minimum age of the previous table. However, the Department ID with the lowest age is 4. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just sort your existing (working) query?  E.g. add `ORDER BY Average_Age LIMIT 1` to the end.

Comment: Thanks that works but can you explain why?

Comment: It's pretty basic.  Which elements of it do you understand, and which do you not?

Comment: I guess I understand when it's ordered it brings the lowest age as the first result along with the correct department. Then I guess that would mean that the LIMIT 1 is seemingly optional.

I'm having trouble understanding why the query does not just grab the correct corresponding DepartmentID in the first place without having to order it.

Comment: The server can return results in any order it wishes *unless one explicitly specifies an `ORDER BY` clause*.  One includes `LIMIT 1` to ensure that *only* the record with the minimal average age is returned and not the whole recordset (of every department and its average age, albeit ordered from youngest to eldest).

Comment: You're mixing together aggregated and non-aggregated columns in the same SELECT query (without GROUP BY).  While MySql (unlike most of other RDBMS) does not prohibit it, it provides no guarantee that non-aggregated value will come from the same row as the aggregated one.

Answer (score 0):

Will you please try this:

```
SELECT department, MIN(avg_age)
FROM
(
    SELECT dept.did AS department, AVG(emp.age) AS avg_age FROM dept
    LEFT JOIN works ON works.did = dept.did
    LEFT JOIN emp ON emp.eid = works.eid
    GROUP BY dept.did
) AS test
ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 1;
```